# Convert timestamp to Epoch date in pl/sql in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, epoch

I want to convert timestamp to Epoch date.

```
SELECT (CAST(timestamp '2022-10-13 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 * 1000 EPOCH_FROM_DATE  
FROM DUAL;
```

This solves my purpose.

But I want it this way:

```
SELECT (CAST(timestamp (to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 * 1000 EPOCH_FROM_DATE  
FROM DUAL;
```

I'm getting an error!

Comment: ***WHAT*** error !?? Remember - we cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to ***SHOW US!***

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want:

- the epoch from midnight of the current day in the UTC time zone then use `SYSTIMESTAMP` and convert it to the `UTC` time zone and then use `TRUNC`.
- the epoch from midnight of the local time zone then use `TRUNC` and cast to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` before converting to `UTC` and then back t a `DATE`:

```sql
SELECT (
         TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
         - date '1970-01-01'
       ) * 86400 * 1000 AS EPOCH_MIDNIGHT_UTC,
       (
         CAST(
           CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
           AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
           AS DATE
         )
         - date '1970-01-01'
       ) * 86400 * 1000 AS EPOCH_MIDNIGHT_CURRENT_TZ
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| EPOCH_MIDNIGHT_UTC | EPOCH_MIDNIGHT_CURRENT_TZ |
| --- | --- |
| 1665705600000 | 1665702000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LAcaR-a-)

Answer (score 0):

So this part right here:

```
timestamp '2022-10-13 00:00:00'
```

Is a *timestamp literal*, and the second part HAS to be a string literal. You can't dynamically create it.

You should use the `to_timestamp()` function instead:

```
SELECT (CAST(to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 * 1000 EPOCH_FROM_DATE  
FROM DUAL;
```

And you can make it a little shorter by leaving out the time (which will be assumed to  be midnight):

```
SELECT (CAST(to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 * 1000 EPOCH_FROM_DATE  
FROM DUAL;
```